# What does $connection_time mean in nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I need some time data for optimizing nginx. But I can not find the meaning of `$connection_time` variable.

Offical document explains(http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_connection_time):

```
connection_time 

    connection time in seconds with a milliseconds resolution (1.19.10)
```

In the access log, I only know `$connection_time` is always greater than `$request_time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$connection_time` is alive time of TCP connection used by a http request.

[HTTP keep-alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) and HTTP/2 allows a single TCP connection to send and receive multiple HTTP requests/responses. so the `$connection_time` should be always greater than `$request_time`;

We can prove it using the following nginx configure file

```
http {
  ...
  log_format testlog '[$time_local] "$request" connection_time= $connection_time request_time= $request_time';
}
```

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /www;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/test.access.log testlog;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/test.error.log;

    # disable cache
    expires -1;
    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    if_modified_since off;
    etag off;

    # disable keep alive
    location /keep-alive-off/ {
        keepalive_timeout 0;
    }

    # enable keep alive
    location /keep-alive-on/ {
        keepalive_timeout 300s;
    }

}
```

access.log

```
[12/Oct/2021:06:38:03 +0000] "GET /keep-alive-off/test.pdf HTTP/1.1" connection_time= 0.212 request_time= 0.210
[12/Oct/2021:06:38:05 +0000] "GET /keep-alive-off/test.pdf HTTP/1.1" connection_time= 0.252 request_time= 0.253
[12/Oct/2021:06:38:06 +0000] "GET /keep-alive-off/test.pdf HTTP/1.1" connection_time= 0.200 request_time= 0.203
[12/Oct/2021:06:38:11 +0000] "GET /keep-alive-on/test.pdf HTTP/1.1" connection_time= 0.240 request_time= 0.239
[12/Oct/2021:06:38:14 +0000] "GET /keep-alive-on/test.pdf HTTP/1.1" connection_time= 3.268 request_time= 0.185
[12/Oct/2021:06:38:17 +0000] "GET /keep-alive-on/test.pdf HTTP/1.1" connection_time= 6.177 request_time= 0.168
```

We can see that if turn off `HTTP keep-alive` to disallow TCP connection reuse, `$request_time` would always be equal with `$connection_time`

Comment: WOW, thx! I got it.  And I also need to study grammer hard.

Comment: s/grammer/grammar/g